# Stash pull request status is not synced in Jira Issue

Tags: git, bitbucket-server

A pull request was approved in stash.However, the status of this pull request shows up in JIRA as "open"

I am trying to find out why the status was not synced up in jira as approved?

Answer (score 1):

There can be only three status of the pull requests. 
1.Open 
2.Merged 
3.Declined

Approved is not a status of Pull request. It is not supposed to get changed in a Jira Issue. However, whenever you click on the created pull request in jira , you can see a green colored approved mark if the code has been approved.